# Preventing other code from changing a variable

Tags: javascript, variables

I don't know where to start or ask, so I came here.

I have three functions (`a`, `b` and `c`) and one variable. Function `a` must be allowed to change the variable, but the other two (`b` & `c`) would only have a permision to read this variable, and its value must be possible to read by any code, anywhere on my website.

Long story short: Only the function 'a' would be able to edit the value of that variable and **no other**. Other code would only be able to read it:

This pseudo-hierarchy would work as shown here:

```js
var data = "some data";


function a() {
  //this function would be able to read & write to 
  //data like so:
  console.log(data);        //reads
  data = 'some other data'; //writes
}
function b() {
  console.log(data);        //reads
  data = 'changed tata';    //This would have to be impossible for that function.
}
function c() {
  // And here the same example as in function b.
}

a(); b(); c();
```

Comment: Do some research on execution context.

Comment: If it's a property of an object, you could use a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) backed by a scoped variable to control changes. Then only code that is within the scope of the backing variable could make changes, while outside code would only be able to read.

Comment: @David784 Thanks! Could you provide a link to some articles explaining it better than just MDN? If it's not a problem?

Comment: `data` should probably be passed as argument to `functionB` and `functionC` (assuming it holds a primitive value). Then you don't have to worry about modifications. "Sharing" data in other ways can be an indicator for bad design.

Comment: Can you provide any pseudo code? Could you wrap function B & C inside function A and make data a constant? :) Could you return function B & C as a result of your function A?

Comment: As I mentioned,` functionA` must have a "permision" to edit `data`, but other not.

Comment: I couldn't add an answer since a hold was put on, but here's a [jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/6s3ovxLh/2/) of what I meant. The backing variable is `_b`, which can only be edited by something inside the `scoped` function. Since `a()` is defined inside `scoped`, it can change `_b`, which consequently changes `obj.b`. But when `b()` tries to directly change `obj.b`, it fails.

Answer (score 1):

This is an XY Problem. If code you don't trust is running in your website's origin, it doesn't matter whether it can write to one of your variables, as it can own the page in a number of other ways instead: replacing all of your code with code that uses some other variable that it can write to, just stealing the authentication data and talking to the server directly itself, etc. The only real solution to your problem is to make sure that all untrusted JavaScript runs in a different origin.

Comment: Then I have no possible options. The code I wanted to work that way was supposted to be a part of my small library. I don't know where it would be used. I only know that some of it's code would have to be blocked from executing by other scripts on the website.

Comment: @AleksanderCiecierski In that case, you made critical, fundamental mistakes in the architecture of your library, and you need to redo it from scratch.

Comment: Maybe I sould ask another question "How not to make mistakes when doing something for the first time?" on stackoverflow. Maybe it won't be a mistake to ask on this exact website :P

Comment: @AleksanderCiecierski You should actually ask a new question that includes more of the code from your library, explains why you need this "security feature", and is asking how to rewrite it so that you don't actually need it.

Comment: The architecture itself isn't bad. I just wanted to add an extra layer of secutiry on top of it. But I suppose I could just set a public `const` containing all the data, and then work with remporary variables inside the function scope that would've originally had the permision to edit that global variable... Maybe it sounds a little strange but I think I know what to do (hopefully).

Comment: @AleksanderCiecierski if doing that to the variables would seem to make it more secure, then either the architecture is bad or you don't understand where the security boundaries actually are.

Comment: Well.. Since it's an anonymus function, I could also just do everything (storing &editing the data) inside it. and then pass it to the global scope after it's finished. Could you provide any articles that could halp me understand this mishmash of secutiry and everything?

Comment: @AleksanderCiecierski if you think **that** would make it more secure, then you are misunderstanding the architecture.